# Replace NaN values in a matrix by keeping the other values in the values untouched

Tags: matlab, matrix, nan

I have a matrix of dimension 2231548x1 and most of the values are NaN. However, some values are between 0 to 1. Instead of using `isfinite(Matrix)` I want only the NaN values as perhaps 0 and the rest as it is(say, 0.345,0.967..etc).

How could I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `isnan()` like this:

```
myMatrix(isnan(myMatrix))=0;
```

A quick explanation: `isnan()` returns `1` (logical `true`) in element `j` if the `j`-th element of its argument is `NaN`. In this manner you rely on logical indexing and you basically say: if you find some `NaN`s in `myMatrix`, return `1` (`true`) and then replace such elements (marked as `true`, i.e. with `NaN`) with a 0 (double 0, not logical 0). The not-`NaN` values will be returned as `false` by `isnan()`, so they will not be touched by logical indexing.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! :)

Comment: You're most certainly welcome!